# How to set up email piping with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I've redirected incoming emails via cPanel to a php script which is below. At the moment it just sends a email reply so I can test that I have the correct info, once I've confirmed that I'll start adding to a database.

What I need to know is how would I use codeigniter to do this?

Also where would I redirect the emails to in cPanel, for example at the moment they go to - public_html/email/parse.php, how would I redirect them to a controller in codeigniter?

I've tried putting this code into a controller but the email bounces back.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// get contents of email and add to $email
$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');

// regular expression to get parts of email that I need
preg_match_all("/(To):\s(.*)\n/i", $email, $to);
preg_match_all("/(Subject):\s(.*)\n/i", $email, $subject);
preg_match_all("/(From):\s(.*)\n/i", $email, $from);

// assign parts of email to variables
$sender = $to[2][0];
$sender = trim($sender, ' " ');

$sender_id  = explode('@', $sender);
$sender_id  = $sender_id[0];

$subject = $subject[2][0];

$from = $from[2][0];

// make a reply email to test the above works
$reply = "Here's your information!\n\nSender: $sender\nSender ID: $sender_id\nFrom:            $from\nSubject: $subject";

// send email to test
mail($from, 'From my email pipe!', $reply, 'From:noreply@mydomain.me');
?>
```

Comment: have tried use `#!/usr/local/bin/php -q` instead of `#!/usr/bin/php -q`